# Is it possible repeating wireless connection with different models of access point?

Tags: wireless-access-point, repeater

I have one Zyxel access point (AP) in my home configured as normal AP.

Becouse wireless signal is not enough to cover all my house, I am going to consider to extend wireless connection with another AP with Repeater functionality.

I precise that Zyxel AP has repeater functionality.

I wonder if it could be possible use another AP of another brand, for example TP-LINK, to solve this problem or I must buy an identical AP?

Thanks.

Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use any repeater.
While configuring the repeater, you'll have to wire it to your computer and probably access a web interface on the repeater (the default IP should be in the booklet)
Then, you can scan networks, find yours, put in the password and there you go, it'll extend your wireless network !
Your material doesn't have to be from the same brand to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this - as long as the wireless type/protocol is the same (eg both are .b or both are .n)

One problem you will find is that while you can add repeaters, each one effectively halves bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use any brand as repeater but very important put auto band with while you are configuring your repeater and don't forget to use same authentication type.